# How does a SwiftUI sheet keep the content from fading out during dismissal

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let's say the sheet's presentation is conditionally dependent on the content not being `nil`. If the content goes `nil` and the sheet hides, the content does not fade out while the sheet is swiping away.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String?
    
    var isPresented: Binding<Bool> {
        .init {
            text != nil
        } set: { presented in
            if !presented {
                text = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
            .onTapGesture {
                text = "Hello, world!"
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: isPresented) {
                Text(text!)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        text = nil
                    }
                    .presentationDetents([.large])
            }
    }
}
```

In the above case, once `text` is set `nil` the sheet will hide and the `Text` content can no longer be drawn because `text` is forcefully unwrapped.

You'd think internally the sheet is conditionally including the content based on `isPresented` but if I try that in my own mock up sheet, the content fades out during the swipe away. If I don't conditionally present the content add always try to render it then there's a crash because `text` has gone `nil` but `Text(text!)` is trying to redraw.

I've tried a number of other things like disabling the animations by using `.transaction { $0.disablesAnimations = true }` or overriding the transition with `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom))` but neither work and the content still fades out.

Comment: I wonder why you use "isPresented" instead of "item"? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/accessorywidgetbackground/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)#

Comment: @OwenZhao I'm not asking so much as to what I should use. What I'm looking for is a little insight to how the `isPresented` variant might work internally. Once `isPresented` has turned `false`, if any part of `content` has also gone `nil` it's assumed any re-renders during slide away would crash, but that's not the case with the sheet.

Comment: I see. In that case, you should aware that the sheet has captured the variable like closure. You must know it and remember it deep. Or you will encounter issue that you thought should never happen. For example, if you change a State value inside the sheet's button and then use the the State value outside the sheet, you will find the @State is still the old value, no change at all.

Comment: Can you show the fadeout transition as a gif? I'm missing it

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, the default behavior is for views to animate smoothly, including fading out during dismissal. However, in your case, you want to bypass this animation for a specific view (Text(text!)) when the text becomes nil.

To achieve this, you can use the .transition modifier along with a custom transition that doesn't include any animation. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve the desired behavior:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String?
    
    var isPresented: Binding<Bool> {
        .init {
            text != nil
        } set: { presented in
            if !presented {
                text = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
            .onTapGesture {
                text = "Hello, world!"
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: isPresented) {
                if let text = text {
                    Text(text)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            text = nil
                        }
                        .transition(.identity) // No animation transition
                        .presentationDetents([.large])
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behaviour where the content inside the sheet doesn't fade out during the swipe-away and doesn't crash when text becomes nil, you can wrap the content in a conditional statement that checks if text is nil. Additionally, you can use a separate @State variable to track the presentation state of the sheet and control the animation. Might be i am wrong, lets try :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String?
    @State private var isSheetPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Color.red
            .onTapGesture {
                text = "Hello, world!"
                isSheetPresented = true // Show the sheet when the color view is tapped
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) { // Use $ to bind isSheetPresented to sheet's isPresented
                if let text = text {
                    Text(text)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            text = nil
                            isSheetPresented = false // Dismiss the sheet when the text is tapped
                        }
                        .transition(.identity)
                        .presentationDetents([.large])
                }
            }
    }
}
```

When you tap on the content or anywhere outside the sheet, it sets text to nil and isSheetPresented to false, dismissing the sheet without the content fading out during the swipe-away.